# django Model have more than one word, verbose_name does not work

Tags: python, django

thanks for help !!! code like this :

```
class MusicCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'分类名称', default='', max_length=200)
    music_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=u'歌曲数目', default=0)
    status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'显示', default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'music_category'
        verbose_name = u'歌曲分类'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

when i go to the admin page, it's still musiccategory but not 歌曲分类。 If i must change the Model name MusicCategory to Category or other Single word?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your post so it matches exactly your code? The code you posted would currently throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Your code works fine on django 1.9.6 what is the version you are using? How are you registering your admin?